# How to mention custom daterange using polars Dataframe in python plotly plots?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, python-polars

I am new to python `polars` and trying to create a `line plot` using `plotly express` with `custom start date` & `max date` as the x-axis date range of the plot.

**Doubt**: Do I need to pass the whole `polars dataframe` again in `fig_pop.update_layout(xaxis_range = )` to set the date range and do the entire `df` processing again or is there an alternative way to this as I already passed the `dataframe` to the `figure object`?

**My code attempt**:

Data processing

```py
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import datetime as dt

# creating pandas df
df_gapminder = px.data.gapminder()

df_gapminder['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_gapminder.year, format="%Y")

# polars dataframe
pl_gapminder = pl.DataFrame(df_gapminder.query('country == "India"'))

pl_gapminder = pl_gapminder.with_columns(pl.col('date').cast(pl.Date))
```

**Doubt** in `fig_pop.update_layout(xaxis_range = )` below section of code

```py
#################      Plotting Below      #################
fig_pop = px.line(pl_gapminder.select(pl.col(['country','date','gdpPercap'])
                        ).to_pandas(),
                        x='date',y='gdpPercap',title="India's GDPPerCap Growth")
fig_pop.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible = True)

# DOUBT in below line: do we need to pass whole dataset again or there is a better way?
fig_pop.update_layout(xaxis_range = ['1977-01-01',pl_gapminder.select(pl.col('date')).max().item()],  
                                showlegend = False,
                                title = {'x':0.5},
                                plot_bgcolor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                                xaxis = (dict(showgrid = False)),
                                yaxis = (dict(showgrid = False)),)
fig_pop.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to pass the whole dataframe again.

Actually `xaxis_range` is a shortcut that uses the [magic underscore notation](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#magic-underscore-notation) for referencing the `range` (nested) property of `xaxis`. So it is set correctly, the problem you have is that setting `xaxis=(...)` in the same call overrides it.

You can do either :

```py
fig_pop.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    title={'x':0.5},
    plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    xaxis=dict(
        showgrid=False, 
        range=['1977-01-01', pl_gapminder['date'].dt.max()]
    ),
    yaxis=dict(showgrid=False)
)
```

Or keep using underscore notation :

```py
fig_pop.update_layout(
    xaxis_range=['1977-01-01', pl_gapminder['date'].dt.max()],
    showlegend=False,
    title={'x':0.5},
    plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    xaxis_showgrid=False,
    yaxis_showgrid=False
)
```

Comment: I was actually thinking about this from `R`'s `tidyverse` perspective of `pipelining`. In `r` we can pass the dataset once for example in this step `fig_pop = px.line(pl_gapminder.select(pl.col(['country','date','gdpPercap'])
                        ).to_pandas()` & also do the transformation within this step and then can refer the same dataset within plotting. This helps in situation if we need the transformed variables again in the plotting steps and don't need to transform it again. But I think its not possible in python/polars so I will accept your answer